# bcp utility throwing Unsupported 16-bit application error

Tags: sql-server, 64-bit, bcp

I am running 64 bit windows 7.

I am 100% positive I am calling bcp from the command line correctly: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe

However, I consistently get an error stating: "The program or feature "\??\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibity (sic) with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available"

I re-installed and repaired the command line utilities. I am totally stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you trying to work with?  2005, 2008, R2, 32, 64 etc.  Also, was an earlier version installed on this box and then another version installed.  I have seen where BCP is still from an older version despite a newer version being installed on top of it.  You can see what version of BCP is the live one by running bcp /v

Comment: I have 2008 R2 x64 and 2005 (looks like x32) installed I believe. bcp /v shows verison 9.00.4035.00.

Comment: BCP 9 is the 2005 version.  See my answer below to get the system to use version 10 like your expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like BCP from 2005 is running when what you really want is the 2008 64 bit to run.

You'll need to update the PATH variable in your system to use the right version of BCP.  See [first paragraph in the REMARKS section in BCP MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for further explanation.

Setting Path on Windows

**Windows 7**

1.Select Computer from the Start menu

2.Choose System Properties from the context menu

3.Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab

4.Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.

5.In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the BCP utility to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.

**Windows XP**

1.Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced

2.Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.

3.In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the BCP utility to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.

4.Close the window.